# Differentiate Rail routes that exist and not found in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to simulate routes from the retailer to the customer in the US in Anylogic and wanted to know what routes could be done by rail. But, if a rail route does not exist I get an error, and the simulation stops. I want the simulation to run and if the route does not exist, it saves in a variable (like a boolean variable, if the route exists it's true and if not is false). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a map object that has the road type set to rail and one that has the road type set to rail

[image]

Then with some simple code, you can check if there is a rail that exists and if not do something else.

```
try {
    GISRoute route = map.getRoute(fromLatitude, fromLongitude, toLatitude, 
    toLatitude);
} catch (Exception e) {
    traceln("Error - no route found - from " + fromLatitude) + ", " + 
    fromLongitude + " to " + toLatitude + ", " + toLongitude);
    traceln("Exception " + e);
    // Maybe look for a road route?
 }
```